# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_16 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=5, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 224, 224, 3]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am using transfer learning with MobileNet and then sending the extracted features to a LSTM for video data classification.

Images are resized to (224,224) when I set the train,test,validation dataset using image_dataset_from_directory().

**EDIT:**
So I need to pad the sequences of the data but I get the following error when I do so, I am not too sure how I can do it when I am using the image_dataset_from_directory():

```
train_dataset = sequence.pad_sequences(train_dataset, maxlen=BATCH_SIZE, padding="post", truncating="post")

InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [Unable to decode bytes as JPEG, PNG, GIF, or BMP]
     [[{{node decode_image/cond_jpeg/else/_1/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/else/_20/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/else/_39/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/Assert/Assert}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]
```

I checked the train_dataset type:

```
<BatchDataset shapes: ((None, None, 224, 224, 3), (None, None)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int32)>
```

**Global variables:**

```
TARGETX = 224
TARGETY = 224
CLASSES = 3
SIZE = (TARGETX,TARGETY)
INPUT_SHAPE = (TARGETX, TARGETY, 3)
CHANNELS = 3
NBFRAME = 5
INSHAPE = (NBFRAME, TARGETX, TARGETY, 3)
```

**Mobilenet function:**

```
def build_mobilenet(shape=INPUT_SHAPE, nbout=CLASSES):
    # INPUT_SHAPE = (224,224,3)
    # CLASSES = 3
    model = MobileNetV2(
        include_top=False,
        input_shape=shape,
        weights='imagenet')
    base_model.trainable = True
    output = GlobalMaxPool2D()
    return Sequential([model, output])
```

**LSTM function:**

```
def action_model(shape=INSHAPE, nbout=3):
    # INSHAPE = (5, 224, 224, 3)
    convnet = build_mobilenet(shape[1:])
    
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(TimeDistributed(convnet, input_shape=shape))
    model.add(LSTM(64))
    model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(.5))
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(.5))
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(.5))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(nbout, activation='softmax'))
    return model
```

```
model = action_model(INSHAPE, CLASSES)
model.summary()
```

```
Model: "sequential_16"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
time_distributed_6 (TimeDist (None, 5, 1280)           2257984   
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_5 (LSTM)                (None, 64)                344320    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_45 (Dense)             (None, 1024)              66560     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_18 (Dropout)         (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_46 (Dense)             (None, 512)               524800    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_19 (Dropout)         (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_47 (Dense)             (None, 128)               65664     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_20 (Dropout)         (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_48 (Dense)             (None, 64)                8256      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_49 (Dense)             (None, 3)                 195       
=================================================================
Total params: 3,267,779
Trainable params: 3,233,667
Non-trainable params: 34,112
```

Comment: The dataset. If it's just a batch of images then that's the problem.

Comment: From what the error says. You're trying to feed something like (32, 224, 224, 3) but your model need (32, 5, 224, 224, 3)

Comment: Must be from INSHAPE then, its shape should be (224,224,3). I was reading the code from an article where they send the number of frames as a sequence in to their model. I'll try it and see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You model is perfectly fine. Its the way you are feeding the data is the problem.

Your model code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.layers import GlobalMaxPool2D, TimeDistributed, Dense, Dropout, LSTM
from keras.applications import MobileNetV2
from keras.models import Sequential
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

TARGETX = 224
TARGETY = 224
CLASSES = 3
SIZE = (TARGETX,TARGETY)
INPUT_SHAPE = (TARGETX, TARGETY, 3)
CHANNELS = 3
NBFRAME = 5
INSHAPE = (NBFRAME, TARGETX, TARGETY, 3)

def build_mobilenet(shape=INPUT_SHAPE, nbout=CLASSES):
    # INPUT_SHAPE = (224,224,3)
    # CLASSES = 3
    model = MobileNetV2(
        include_top=False,
        input_shape=shape,
        weights='imagenet')
    model.trainable = True
    output = GlobalMaxPool2D()
    return Sequential([model, output])

def action_model(shape=INSHAPE, nbout=3):
    # INSHAPE = (5, 224, 224, 3)
    convnet = build_mobilenet(shape[1:])
    
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(TimeDistributed(convnet, input_shape=shape))
    model.add(LSTM(64))
    model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(.5))
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(.5))
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(.5))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(nbout, activation='softmax'))
    return model
```

Lets try out this model with some dummy data now:

So you model accepts a sequence of images (i.e frames of the video) and classified them (the video) into one of the 3 classes.

Lets create a dummy data with 4 videos each of 10 frames, i.e batch size = 4 and time steps = 10

```
X = np.random.randn(4, 10, TARGETX, TARGETY, 3)
y = model(X)
print (y.shape)
```

Output:

```
(4,3)
```

As expected the output size is `(4,3)`

Now the problem you will be facing with using `image_dataset_from_direcctory` will be how to batch variable length videos since the number of frames in each video will/might vary.  The way to handle it is using `pad_sequences`.

For example if first video has 10 frames second has 9 and so on you can do something like below

```
X = [np.random.randn(10, TARGETX, TARGETY, 3), 
     np.random.randn(9, TARGETX, TARGETY, 3), 
     np.random.randn(8, TARGETX, TARGETY, 3), 
     np.random.randn(7, TARGETX, TARGETY, 3)]

X = pad_sequences(X)
y = model(X)
print (y.shape)
```

Output:

```
(4,3)
```

So once you read images using `image_dataset_from_direcctory` you will have to pad the variable length frames into batch.

Comment: So I will have to apply pad_sequences() to my train, test and validation dataset before training the model? I'm a bit confused about the part on the number of frames as my initial dataset had many videos of each category(60 for each and each one was about 10 mins long, I took a frame every 5s) then after processing them I combined them into a big folder for each category.

Comment: Yes so based on the length of the video you will have different number of frames. So when you create a batch you will have to pad the shorter frames. This is because all the samples in a batch should have same number of timesteps. You can have batch size of 1 and not worry about padding but this will slow down your training time.

Comment: Ok got it so I need to pad the sequences of frames in order to maintain a fixed shape across all of the batches. Isn't this like in NLP where word sequences are padded to give a fixed sequence as sentences vary in length?

Comment: Yes exactly, it is same as how you handle variable length sentences. In fact all the models which use RNNs have to deal with this problem.

Comment: Hey could you check the edited post? I have issues padding the frames.